# comparing and counting items in python (while loop)

Tags: python, while-loop, readline, counting

I'm trying to make a script that:

- Reads in a line of text line-by-line from a file
- For each line, see if any phrases from an array (animal_keywords) are there
- If there is, increase the animal count by 1
- If there isn't, increase the other count by 1
- Print the count at the end

My input file is list.txt (the count should be animals:9 and other:3)

```
C\Documents\Panda\Egg1
D\Media\Elephant\No
F\Pictures\tree
H\Lemur\12
C\Documents\Panda\Egg1
D\Media\Elephant\No
F\Pictures\tree
H\Lemur\12
C\Documents\Panda\Egg1
D\Media\Elephant\No
F\Pictures\tree
H\Lemur\12
```

My script is:

```
## Import packages
from time import sleep
import os

## Set up counts
animal_count = 0
other_count = 0

## List of known keywords (Animals)
animal_keywords = ['Panda', 'Elephant', 'Lemur']


## Open file, read only
f = open('list.txt')

## Read first line
line = f.readline()

##If file not empty, read lines one at a time until empty
while line:
    print line
    line = f.readline()

    if any(x in f for x in animal_keywords):
        animal_count = animal_count +1

    ##If it doesn't, increase the other count
    else:
        other_count = other_count + 1

f.close()

print 'Animals found:', animal_count, '|||| ' 'Others found:', other_count
```

The script doesn't read the lines properly or do the count correctly. I've been going round in circles!

The output I am getting currently is:

```
C\Documents\Panda\Egg1

D\Media\Elephant\No

Animals found: 0 |||| Others found: 2
```

Comment: What's not going right exactly? What output/errors are you getting?

Comment: You are skipping the first line by calling readline() twice before using the `line` variable.

Comment: There is no need for a while loop, the correct way would be to simply iterate over the file object

Comment: What do you think `x in f` does? How would it be different to `x in line`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over the file object checking if any animal keyword is in each line:

```
animal_count = 0
other_count = 0

## List of known keywords (Animals)
animal_keywords = ['Panda', 'Elephant', 'Lemur']

# with will automatically close your file
with open("list.txt") as f:
    # iterate over the file object, getting each line
    for line in f:
        # if any keyword is in the line, increase animal count
        if any(animal in line for animal in animal_keywords):
            animal_count += 1
        # else there was no keyword in the line so increase other
        else:
            other_count += 1
```

Comment: That is awesome, thank you! Put that bit in place and it works now! Thank you - very much appreciated!

Comment: @CuriousGeorgem no worries, you're welcome. This is the idiomatic way to open and read a file in python.

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

```
if any(x in f for x in animal_keywords):
        animal_count = animal_count +1
```

will be `True` for every iteration of the while loop.
So, most likely you are getting a +1 for `animal_count` for 
every line in the file, whether it has an animal or not

You want something more like:

```
with open('list.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if any(a in line for a in animal_keywords):
            animal_count += 1
        else:
            other_count += 1
```

The file is auto closed after the code in the 'with block' is executed, so
it's good practice.